# How to save user's input

Tags: save

For exm, I enter the text in the app and when I start the app next time, that it is still there. As a planner, notes, etc. I don't know if I should somehow use a button or something similar. I tried to find an answer on the Internet, but I didn't find anything that exactly answered my "problem"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

We want to assign the input to a variable, which can later be called. This is done differently in different languages. Often a binding $ is used.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).